# Spring Test. Get access of test class of dependent project?

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit, spring-boot

I have multi module projects; I am creating Junit Test classes for testing purpose.

***But the problem is, when I run my Core Project Test using only 2 package ComponentScan for testing. It is not able to locate Util Project Test config.(Test package get excluded while building JAR)***

*Because of this, I am getting, **No qualifying bean of type** exception as Configuration class is missing from Util project.*

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = { CreateProfileTest.class })
@ComponentScan({"com.myproject.testconfig","com.myproject.module"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class CreateProfileTest {


    @Test
    public void myMethod()
    {

    }
}
```

So, How I can gain access to Util Project Test Config in Core Project Test.

Job - > Core -> Util (Here Core is depend on Util)

Now

```
 CoreProject/
             src/main/com.myproject.config
             src/main/com.myproject.module
             src/test/com.myproject.testconfig 

 UtilPorject/
             src/main/com.myproject.config
             src/main/com.myproject.module
             src/test/com.myproject.testconfig
```

Please let me know, If there is any alternative way to achieve this or if I am doing anything wrong here.

I am using Maven and Spring Boot.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me this is a matter of classpath. Have you tried adding this in the CoreProject pom.xml ?

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>...</groupId>
        <artifactId>util-project</artifactId>
        <version>...</version>
        <classifier>tests</classifier>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```